# Similar looking XSLT transforms not working

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Input XML

```
<Web-inf>
  <A>
    <A1>Val1</A1>
    <A1>Val1</A1>
    <A1>Val1</A1>
  </A>

  <A>
    <A1>Val2</A1>
    <A1>Val2</A1>
    <A1>Val2</A1>
  </A>

  <B>
   <B1>Hi</B1>
  </B>

  <B>
   <B1>Bye</B1>   
  </B>

  <C>DummyC</C>

  <D>DummyD</D>

</Web-inf>
```

I want to add `<B>` tag if it doesn't already exist with `<B1>` value as "Morning" and "Evening". If it exists i don't do anything. I have written following transform but the strange issue is that only the LATER one works and FIRST one is ignored completely. As a result only `<B><B1>Evening</B1></B>` is only inserted along with `<B>` tags. Is that a known issue? If yes, how to correct it?

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Web-inf[not(B[B1='Morning'])]/B[last()]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
      <B>
         <B1>Morning</B1>
      </B>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Web-inf[not(B[B1='Evening'])]/B[last()]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
      <B>
         <B1>Evening</B1>
      </B>
</xsl:template>
```

I want the O/P XML to be as below

Output.xml

```
<Web-inf>
  <A>
    <A1>Val1</A1>
    <A1>Val1</A1>
    <A1>Val1</A1>
  </A>

  <A>
    <A1>Val2</A1>
    <A1>Val2</A1>
    <A1>Val2</A1>
  </A>

  <B>
   <B1>Hi</B1>
  </B>

  <B>
   <B1>Bye</B1>   
  </B>

  <B>
   <B1>Morning</B1>   
  </B>
  <B>
   <B1>Evening</B1>   
  </B>

  <C>DummyC</C>

  <D>DummyD</D>

</Web-inf>
```

Answer (score 0):

For you given input XML, both templates for `B[last()]` will be matched. When two templates match an element with equal priority, this is considered an error. The XSLT processor will either flag the error, or ignore all but the last matching template.

In this case, it might simply be better to have single template matching `B[last()]` and have the other conditions as `xsl:if` statements in the template.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Web-inf/B[last()]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
        <xsl:if test="not(../B[B1='Morning'])">
          <B>
             <B1>Morning</B1>
          </B>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(../B[B1='Evening'])">
          <B>
             <B1>Evening</B1>
          </B>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```